# Get file from bitbucket (git) from powershell

Tags: powershell, git

I need to grab a single file from bitbucket (git) using powershell. Complicating matters I need to do so over http/https as the system I'm running powershell from does not have direct internet access (therefore ssh isn't an option). How can I do so?

I thought that perhaps I could grab it using Invoke-WebRequest and accessing the raw URL. For example: https://bitbucket.org/company/project/raw/HEAD/some/special/file.txt

But it appears to access that you have to authenticate. I've tried setting up authentication but I can't get it working.

I thought next I could just pull it from git using git archive:
git archive --remote=git://bitbucket.org/Company/project.git HEAD:some/path/file.txt but that also doesn't seem to work.

So how can I get a single file. I don't want to just do git clone because then I have to pull down (and store) 500MB worth of other files I don't care about in the repo which is an issue for two reasons

```
1) I have to have space to store all that data (at least temporarily)
2) Unless I want to tie up that storage permanently I have to re-download it each time I need the file.
```

The file I need is 10KB so to tie up 500MB for a 10kb file seems absurd.

What's the answer? There's got to be a way to get Invoke-WebRequest to authenticate properly or just download a single file? Can any git gurus - particularly with powershell/windows backgrounds help?

Thanks!
Brad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BitBucket appears to have a pretty standard REST API you can use with [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) or [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod).

Here are some links to their documentation: [Authentication](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-bitbucket-cloud-rest-apis-222724129.html) and [GET raw content](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/src-resources-296095214.html#srcResources-GETrawcontentofanindividualfile).  The gist of those doc pages is that they support basic authentication and GET requests for raw file contents.  So from your example, you'd need to do something like this:

```
# create a credential variable for your account
$cred = Get-Credential

# modify the base URL to hit the API endpoint instead of the standard web endpoint, pass the credentials with the request, and send the output to a file
Invoke-RestMethod -Credential $cred -Uri https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/company/project/raw/HEAD/some/special/file.txt -OutFile .\file.txt
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. I saw the web api documents but I couldn't work out if it was possible to retrieve a file using them. Let me give that a try and i'll follow up.

Comment: That works perfectly - thank you! I was banging my head off the wall trying to figure out how to do that :)

Comment: I tried `wget`, `curl`, `Invoke-WebRequest` but they all did not work, Invoke-RestMethod was the right method :)